# PHP Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to use a PHP connection to connect MySQL Database which is on phpmyadmin. Nothing fancy about the connection just trying to see whether the connection is successful or not. I am using MAMP to host the database, the connection I am trying to use is this:

```
<?php
$servername = "127.0.0.1";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=AppDatabase", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected successfully"; 
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

I have been using postman to test to see if the connection is working, but I keep receiving this error message:

> Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

Before I was receiving an error message of:

> Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

This was because I had set the servername to localhost, through changing this to the IP address it has given me connection refused and I have no idea what is wrong.

Any help regarding this would be appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like your MySQL service is not listening on 127.0.0.1 TCP. If it is actually running at all, it may be that it is on a local socket but not TCP. Does `mysql:localhost;dbname=AppDatabase` make a difference?

Comment: ... or was the "no such file or directory" happening with `localhost`? If that was the case, either the socket path was incorrect in php.ini, or MySQL is not running at all.

Comment: In case someone else has this problem for the same reason I did, for me the problem was that I made a mistake in my code which caused me to be logged in to the database with the wrong host name.

Comment: You might get the same error for out of disk space for MySQL. If your on Ubuntu, check the disk spaces ```$ df -h```

Answer (score 70, accepted):

I found the reason why the connection was not working, it was because the connection was trying to connect to port 8888, when it needed to connect to port 8889.

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;port=8889;dbname=AppDatabase", $username, $password);
```

This fixed the problem, although changing the server name to localhost still gives the error.

Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

But it connects successfully when the IP address is entered for the server name.

Comment: Try to do a `ping localhost` to see wether it ping to the loopback address. Could be your hosts files is corrupted.Using the IP over the hostname will provide a small performance boost anyway

Comment: How did you figure out the right port? Isn't by default the local host port 8080? Does that change when you use the tcp protocol?

Comment: I believe this has something to do with ipv6. The host localhost for me resolves to `::1`, so I'm suspecting the underlying mysql client doesn't have ipv6 support (even for local addresses). Changing it to 127.0.0.1 resolved it for me, like the last line of the answer suggests.

Comment: I got the same error message when using Laradock.io (Laravel 8), however then I needed to update it to use my real IP-adress to solve it. I guess due to the code access was done inside the docker container.

Answer (score 17):

I spent quite a few hours in a `docker` environment where all my containers are `docker` containers and I was using `Phinx` for migrations. Just to share different responses with different configurations.

**Working solutions**

```
"host" => "db", // {docker container's name} Worked
"host" => "172.22.112.1", // {some docker IP through ipconfig - may change on every instance - usually something like 172.x.x.x} Worked
```

**Non-working solutions**

```
"host" => "127.0.0.1", // SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
"host" => "docker.host.internal", //  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name does not resolve
"host" => "localhost", //  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
```

I was running `Phinx` in following way.

```
docker compose --env-file .env run --rm phinx status -e development
```

Comment: Actually to me work changing the localhost to the name of the service

Comment: Same here! This saved me a lot of time.

Comment: thanks a lot for the examples, mine worked with the docker container's name :-)
Had to remove the 'port' option though

Answer (score 7):

In my case MySQL sever was not running. I restarted the MySQL server and issue was resolved.

```
//on ubuntu server
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

To avoid MySQL stop problem, you can use the "initctl" utility in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Linux to make sure the service restarts in case of a failure or reboot. Please consider talking a snapshot of root volume (with mysql stopped) before performing this operations for data retention purpose[8]. You can use the following commands to manage the mysql service with "initctl" utility with stop and start operations.

```
$ sudo initctl stop mysql
$ sudo initctl start mysql
```

To verify the working, you can check the status of the service and get
the process id (pid), simulate a failure by killing the "mysql"
process and verify its status as running with new process id after
sometime (typically within 1 minute) using the following commands.

```
$ sudo initctl status mysql         # get pid
$ sudo kill -9 <pid>                # kill mysql process
$ sudo initctl status mysql         # verify status as running after sometime
```

> **Note : In latest Ubuntu version now initctl is replaced by systemctl**

Comment: So what's your answer as to why the connection failed error is coming? Seems like this is addressing how to start and stop mysql service, might have missed it.

Comment: Please check my first line where I clearly stated that , In my case server automatically stopped and I was not aware about that. So to solve the issue where server stopped I just used above statements to prevent unexpected server halting issue. Hope that make sense.

Comment: Sure, that's easy to see, but/and since it's not addressing the error codes or the inability to connect to the database, it seems like an alternate issue, etc. I was coming here last night to debug some problems on a mariadb instance and spent like 5 minutes reading your post to see if I was missing something, but/and it was merely informing people how to start/stop a service, not why you might get those errors when the service is confirmed running, as is the case with the OP. Usually, people providing answers to unrelated questions, note that at the top of the post to help readers.

Answer (score 3):

Using MAMP I changed the `host=localhost` to `host=127.0.0.1`. But a new issue came **"connection refused"**

Solved this by putting `'port' => '8889'`, in `'Datasources' => [`

Answer (score 2):

#### 1. server cert verify flag

I was required to use SSL to connect, and needed to set `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT` to false in the `new PDO` options array, besides the entry `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA` for the CA file.

Without it, the mysql log on the server helpfully mentions

```
2021-07-27 17:02:51 597605 [Warning] Aborted connection 597605 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '192.168.10.123' (This connection closed normally without authentication)
```

where I was definitely passing the right db and username and such in the DSN. An empty options array *will* show the db and user in the error log, at least. I am sure there is a valid, technical reason for these things.
I am adding this information so I can more easily find it, the next time I end up on this page..

#### 2. host in connection string

In the context of SSL, I've also seen the error when using the IP address instead of the hostname to connect, if the hostname was used as CN (Common Name) in the certificate.

Answer (score 1):

Using MAMP ON Mac, I solve my problem by renaming

```
/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock.lock
```

to

```
/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Answer (score 0):

For me was php version from mac instead of MAMP, PATH variable on .bash_profile was wrong. I just prepend the MAMP PHP bin folder to the $PATH env variable. For me was:

```
/Applications/mampstack-7.1.21-0/php/bin
```

1. In terminal run `vim ~/.bash_profile` to open `~/.bash_profile`
2. Type i to be able to edit the file, add the bin directory as PATH variable on the top to the file:

   export PATH="/Applications/mampstack-7.1.21-0/php/bin/:$PATH"
3. Hit `ESC`, Type `:wq`, and hit `Enter`
4. In Terminal run `source ~/.bash_profile`
5. In Terminal type `which php`, output should be the path to MAMP PHP install.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on a docker container from `php:8.0-fpm-alpine` image. I just added the following line in the Dockerfile and it fixed the issue:

```
RUN apk add mysql-client
```

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem once, turned out the User in the database was created with something like:

```
CREATE USER 'webpage'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

worked fine when the connection details php script had localhost, but not when the IP address was there. A quick swap (ip address when creating user and localhost in connection details) revealed those two things have to match.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32474556)

Answer (score -4):

For everyone if you still strugle with Refusing connection, here is my advice. Download XAMPP or other similar sw and just start MySQL. You dont have to run apache or other things just the MySQL.

Comment: How does installing another software resolve the given problem? What if the same problem occurs and XAMPP is already installed?