# Connection Refuse exception occur in drive: SQLSTATE[HY000}[2002]

Tags: php, mysql, docker, docker-compose, symfony4

So I am starting a docker symfony 4 project and i am trying to use a controller.  I already created the database that i need by running 
    doctrine:database:create

and it work and created my database so the connection is good.  however, when i run this code below.  I get that error.   I a little confuse on why mysql doesnt connect.  anyone know?

Ive tried change mysql versions, composing it down and updating different mysql root and password and is not connecting.

```
class HospitalAdminController extends AbstractController
{
     /**
     * @Route("/admin/hospital/new")
     */
    public function new(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $hospital = new Hospital();
        $hospital->setName('Example Hospital')
            ->setPhone(8175831483)
            ->setAddress('123 Avenue');

        $em->persist($hospital);
        $em->flush();


        return new Response(sprintf(
            'Hiya! New Hospital id: #%d phone:%s address%s',
            $hospital->getId(),
            $hospital->getPhone(),
            $hospital->getAddress()

        ));

    }
}
```

just trying to run my controller and do a proof of concept.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Connection failed: SQLSTATE\[HY000\] \[2002\] Connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29395452/php-connection-failed-sqlstatehy000-2002-connection-refused)

Comment: what are the connection parameters you are using?