# Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused When Trying to Connect to MySQL Through Docker

Tags: php, mysql, docker, pdo, docker-compose

The problem that I am experiencing is that when I try to connect to the database that is in a docker container, I keep getting the error `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused` through PDO. I have tried the methods mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29395452/php-connection-failed-sqlstatehy000-2002-connection-refused) as well as some other posts that say very similar things, to no avail. MySQL is currently active, and ready to accept connections. I am running Docker Engine `19.03.12` Compose `1.26.2` Docker Desktop `2.3.0.4 (46911)` with Compose File version `3.8`. Below is my *docker-compose.yml*:

```
version: "3.8"
services: 
  web: 
    build: 
      context: ./php
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: php74
    depends_on: 
      - database
    ports: 
      - "8000:80"
    volumes: 
      - "./php:/var/www/html"
  database: 
    command: "--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password"
    container_name: mysql8
    environment: 
      MYSQL_DATABASE: quizzane
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_USER: quizzane
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "QFtdFZk2wC-c4skfJ?5#TPLrXyeZVTJ99=s*GEBVR_!XQ9B?_?NE+Dwc7pL!2fzb"
    image: "mysql:8.0.21"
    ports: 
      - "6033:3306"
    restart: always
```

and then my *Dockerfile*:

```
FROM php:7.4.9-apache
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install openssl curl zlib1g-dev enchant libsodium-dev libzip-dev bzip2 libcurl4-openssl-dev libssl-dev libpng-dev libgmp-dev libxml2-dev libenchant-dev libc-client2007e-dev libc-client-dev libkrb5-dev libonig-dev libedit-dev libtidy-dev libxslt-dev libgd2-xpm-dev -y
RUN docker-php-ext-configure imap --with-kerberos --with-imap-ssl
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/
RUN docker-php-ext-install bcmath calendar ctype curl enchant exif ffi ftp gd gmp iconv imap intl mbstring pcntl pdo pdo_mysql readline shmop soap sockets sodium sysvmsg sysvsem sysvshm tidy tokenizer xsl zip -j$(nproc)
RUN ls /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/
EXPOSE 80
```

and my PDO connection file:

```
try {
    $datasource = 'mysql:host=127.18.0.2;port=6033;dbname=quizzane';
    $username = 'quizzane';
    $password = 'QFtdFZk2wC-c4skfJ?5#TPLrXyeZVTJ99=s*GEBVR_!XQ9B?_?NE+Dwc7pL!2fzb';
    $pdo = new PDO($datasource, $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected successfully"; 
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

The IP that is not localhost is the IP of the docker container. Here is part of what MySQL shows when starting up:

```
mysql8      | 2020-08-30T17:19:08.484523Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.21'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

Comment: There are a lot of Dockerised Apache/Nginx&MySQL&PHP examples [here](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/posts/docker). Check if they help.

Comment: Replacing some code from [this](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/su76/creating-apache-mysql-and-php-fpm-containers-for-a-web-application-with-docker-compose) into PDO worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: The IP address is probably wrong, but you can use the Compose service name `database` as a host name.  You need to connect to the normal MySQL port 3306; `ports:` aren't used at all for connections between containers.  [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) describes the overall network environment a little more.

Comment: I have taken this into account. The IP address is actually correct and the ports also. I can successfully connect to the database. ```ports:``` is used for binding if I'm not mistaken. I need this because I have a regular MySQL server installation and one in docker. They conflict.