# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] laravel migrations error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I run php artisan migrate, my basic migrations are taking a very long time. Then the database server is restarted and laravel returns an error `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused`.

[image]

What could be the problem?

My **.env** db

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=db_name
DB_USERNAME=laravel
DB_PASSWORD="passw#"
```

My **config/database.php**

```
    'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),

    ....

        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],

        .....
```

**MySql version**

```
8.0.30-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 (Ubuntu)
```

**mysql-logs**

```
2022-09-06T08:06:01.880939Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.30-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) starting as process 60463
2022-09-06T08:06:01.895767Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2022-09-06T08:06:02.442108Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2022-09-06T08:06:02.640013Z 0 [System] [MY-010229] [Server] Starting XA crash recovery...
2022-09-06T08:06:02.667853Z 0 [System] [MY-010232] [Server] XA crash recovery finished.
2022-09-06T08:06:02.744622Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2022-09-06T08:06:02.744859Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2022-09-06T08:06:02.780189Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.30-0ubuntu0.20.04.2'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu).
2022-09-06T08:06:02.780471Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '127.0.0.1' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
```

Answer (score 0):

there is no issue with the DB migrations are running but it is complaining due to an existing record on the failed jobs table,instead try [this](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#generating-migrations) command and rerun the seeder again.

```
php artisan migrate:refresh
```

Answer (score -2):

Maybe your problem is on the connection port you are using, take a look at this threat, hope it helps [PHP Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29395452/php-connection-failed-sqlstatehy000-2002-connection-refused)

Comment: the pointed link is unrelated to the question, thanks

Comment: it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here in case the linked page changes