# Troubleshooting Laravel Environment Variables on Kubernetes

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-eks

I'm currently facing an issue with running Laravel on Kubernetes, particularly with environment variables.

Here's the situation: I've successfully deployed Laravel on Kubernetes, but I'm encountering difficulties with environment variables. I've stored the Laravel environment variables in a Kubernetes Secret, and when I inspect the container and run `printenv`, I can see that the RDS credentials are correctly populated from the Secret. However, when I attempt to access any API endpoint, I encounter the following error:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (Connection: mysql, SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from 'users' where 'email' = jhon@gmail.com) in file /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php on line 829
```

I've heard that Laravel on Kubernetes is capable of retrieving environment variables directly from PHP rather than from the `.env` file. Do I need to enable this feature, and if so, how? Additionally, I'm trying to avoid using a .env file to avoid the need to create a separate Docker image for each environment.

I can see all variables with dynamic values when I run printenv into the pod in exec mode that i have added in `configmap.yml` and `secret.yml` file

I have also tried with `AppServiceProvider` like this but did not work

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class EnvironmentConfigServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
   /**
    * Register services.
    */
   public function register(): void
   {
    $this->app->singleton('mysql_credentials', function () {
        // Fetch MySQL credentials dynamically from your provider
        $host = config('database.connections.mysql.host');
        $port = config('database.connections.mysql.port');
        $database = config('database.connections.mysql.database');
        $username = config('database.connections.mysql.username');
        $password = config('database.connections.mysql.password');

        return [
            'host' => $host,
            'port' => $port,
            'database' => $database,
            'username' => $username,
            'password' => $password,
        ];
    });
   }

   /**
    * Bootstrap services.
    */
   public function boot(): void
   {
       //
   }
}
```

Why I tried that because after `exec` mode into Pod i can see all values of my RDS credential that i have set in `secret.yml` file

```
ubuntu@ip-xxxxxxxxxxx:/ecom-prod$ kubectl exec -it pod/ecom-xxxxxxxx-kb62z -n ecom-eks -- bash
root@ecom-kb62z:/var/www# php artisan tinker
Psy Shell v0.12.0 (PHP 8.1.27 — cli) by Justin Hileman
> config('database.connections.mysql.username');
= "root"

> config('database.connections.mysql.password');
= "xxxxx"

> config('database.connections.mysql.database');
= "xxxxxxxx"

> config('database.connections.mysql.host');
= "ecomc7.xxxxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com"

> config('database.connections.mysql.port');
= "3306"
```

I can access RDS from my server with the RDS endpoint(as a host), username and password and also there is a database and tables

```
ubuntu@ip-xxxxxxxxxxx:/ecom-prod$ mysql -h ecom-db-identifier.xxxxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -u root -p
Enter password: xxxxx
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 113
Server version: 8.0.35 Source distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2024, Oracle and/or its affiliates.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| ecom       |
| sys                |
+--------------------+
5 rows in set (0.29 sec)

mysql> use ecom
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed
mysql> show tables;
+------------------------+
| Tables_in_ecom |
+------------------------+
| activity_log           |
| comments               |
| failed_jobs            |
| migrations             |
| password_reset_tokens  |
| permissions            |
| personal_access_tokens |
| policies               |
| users                  |
+------------------------+
28 rows in set (0.28 sec)

mysql>
```

```
root@ecom-kb62z:/var/www# php artisan tinker
Psy Shell v0.12.0 (PHP 8.1.27 — cli) by Justin Hileman
> config('database.default');
= "mysql"

> config('database.connections.mysql');
= [
    "driver" => "mysql",
    "url" => null,
    "host" => "ecom-identifier.xxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com",
    "port" => "3306",
    "database" => "ecom",
    "username" => "root",
    "password" => "xxxxxx",
    "unix_socket" => "",
    "charset" => "utf8mb4",
    "collation" => "utf8mb4_unicode_ci",
    "prefix" => "",
    "prefix_indexes" => true,
    "strict" => true,
    "engine" => null,
    "options" => [],
  ]
```

within tinker: `App\Models\User::find(1);`

```
root@ecom-deployment-xxxxxxx-kb62z:/var/www# php artisan tinker
Psy Shell v0.12.0 (PHP 8.1.27 — cli) by Justin Hileman
> App\Models\User::find(1);
= App\Models\User {#5534
    id: 1,
    name: "Test User",
    email: "test@example.com",
    #email_verified_at: "2024-03-12 15:52:14",
    #password: "y$.bHDGgvm4zY.ucub4L.avOcERJzaS72sC0GZna6cAhy2/3xI1Cr/e",
    image: null,
    #remember_token: "SnA9FiQFl8",
    created_at: "2024-03-12 15:52:14",
    updated_at: "2024-03-12 15:52:14",
  }
```

also, I did check to run the command into the exec mode of a pod

like `php artisan db:seed` that is also work

```
root@ecom-deployment-xxxxx-kb62z:/var/www# php artisan db:seed

   INFO  Seeding database.  

  Database\Seeders\PermissionsSeeder ................................................................................................. RUNNING  
  Database\Seeders\PermissionsSeeder ............................................................................................... 6 ms DONE  

  Database\Seeders\RolesSeeder ....................................................................................................... RUNNING  
  Database\Seeders\RolesSeeder ..................................................................................................... 6 ms DONE  

  Database\Seeders\RolePermissionsSeeder ............................................................................................. RUNNING  
  Database\Seeders\RolePermissionsSeeder ......................................................................................... 104 ms DONE
```

I'm confused if everything is working into the exec pod then why the connection is not built

Could you please provide guidance on how to set up Laravel environment variables effectively on Kubernetes? Thank you.

Comment: "SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused" is pretty straighforward. Do you have the correct host in your `.env` file? If so, it sounds like a network connectivity issue, maybe a firewall.

Comment: And I don't know what you're doing with `AppServiceProvider`, the database is configured in the `config/database.php` file.

Comment: I'm not using it ``.env`` for MySQL credential, I'm using Kubernetes ``secrets`` , I have added detail in my question.
I can see with ``printenv`` in the pod

Comment: I had just tried with ``AppServiceProvider``to i could give MySQL credentials on run time. that's why i used

Comment: I can see my mysql credentials after exec into the pod with ``printenv`` command there I have checked everything is correct.

Comment: @miken32, did you get it

Comment: I'm a programmer, not a kubernetes admin, sorry

Comment: Oh, okay @miken32 np

Comment: that error is when the database refuses to allows the connection, does not mean the user or password are wrong, that is a different issues, so you are lacking the access from your database (exposed)

Comment: Thanks, @matiaslauriti for replying to me. Would you like to tell me that how can i solve this issue. Thanks

Comment: Depends a lot on what the issue may be, but google the error... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29395452/php-connection-failed-sqlstatehy000-2002-connection-refused

Comment: Why do you want to close this issue? however, I have explained everything. you can ask me if something is confusing you.